# Is level set of Busemann function on Alexandrov space again Alexandrov space? 

Tags: alexandrov-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

M is an Alexandrov space with curv>=-1,containing a line(ray).Is level set of Busemann function on M again Alexandrov space?If not,can you give a counterexample?

Comment: Can you cut and paste questions from assignments? ;-) If not, I apologise, but please have a read of http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask 

Comment: No, consider the quotient $\mathbb H^3/\iota$, where $\iota$ is rotation around a line. 